# How to understand and use `<fx:root>` , in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, nested

It says tag `fx:root` has been added to javafx 2.2, but I don't understand how to use it, although with this sample: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm

**main.xml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <fx:include fx:id="editorPane" source="editor.fxml"/>
</GridPane>
```

**editor.fxml** without `fx:root`:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<TextArea fx:id="editor" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="400" 
   fx:controller="sample.EditorController"
   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"/>
```

**editor.fxml** with `fx:root`:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.TextArea"
     fx:id="editor" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="400"
     fx:controller="sample.EditorController"
     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"/>
```

Actually, I can't find any difference for the two kinds of code. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`<fx:root>` provides a solution to the issue of defining a reusable component with FXML.

As an example, imagine you want to define a simple custom component consisting of a `TextField` and `Button` contained in an `HBox`. You need this to be represented by a subclass of `Node`, so you can write code like

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.getChildren().add(new MyComponent());
```

The issue is you need a Java class which is a subclass of `Node`, as well as the FXML. In pure Java (no FXML), you could do this with:

```
public class MyComponent extends HBox {
    private TextField textField ;
    private Button button ;

    public MyComponent() {
        textField = new TextField();
        button = new Button();
        this.getChildren().addAll(textField, button);
    }
}
```

Using FXML to define the custom component without the `<fx:root>` element presents a problem, because you need the FXML to be some kind of node, and then another node instance to represent the class wrapping it:

```
<HBox>
<TextField fx:id="textField"/>
<Button fx:id="button" />
</HBox>
```

and

```
public class MyComponent extends HBox {
    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;
    @FXML
    private Button button ;
    public MyComponent() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyComponent.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            HBox hbox = loader.load();
            this.getChildren().add(hbox);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

This results in MyComponent consisting of an HBox wrapping an HBox wrapping the TextField and Button. The additional, redundant HBox is a result of needing one Node for the FXML root and one Node to represent the component.

`<fx:root>` gives a mechanism to create the Node as the component (the Java class) and then to instruct the FXML file to use that node as its root:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox">
<TextField fx:id="textField" />
<Button fx:id="button" />
</fx:root>
```

and

```
public class MyComponent extends HBox {
    @FXML 
    private TextField textField ;
    @FXML
    private Button button ;
    public MyComponent() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyComponent.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Now `MyComponent` has the same structure as the original all-Java version, an `HBox` containing a `TextField` and a `Button`. You can't do this using FXML without the `<fx:root>` element.

Comment: And important part is also, that you can then use MyComponent in other FXML documents like any other control. You can create whole hierarchies like this.

Comment: I see a problem in providing a ResourceBundle for the FXMLLoader(fxml, bundle). I mean, if you use this in another FXML file you have to have a default constructor. I can pass the ResourceBundle later, but I wonder if there is a way to provide it at construction?

Comment: @solarisx You can provide constructor arguments if you annotate them `@NamedArg`, i.e. `public MyComponent(@NamedArg("resources") ResourceBundle resources) { ... }`. The FXML file by default has an element called `resources` in the namespace, so, while I haven't tested this, I *think* you should be able to do `<MyComponent resources="${resources}">`.

Comment: @James_D <MyComponent resources="${resources}"> does not work. Any other idea?